# How to move table data in a td to upwards td if td is empty

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have two very simple `html table`  with some data distributed in it please see the code below This is what i have done until now. I have got stuck up here please help me out.

```
var x = 0,y=0;
$("table tr td").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() !== ""){
        alert($(this).text());
        y++;
    }
    x++;
});
alert(x);//indicates how many td's 
alert(y);//indicates how many td have values
```

Now, I just want to move the data in each td to upwards td if there is no data in it. Please click on Js FIDDLE link down below

[JS FIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/twkUR/5/)

Comment: What do you mean by "upwards"? To the row above it? It's important that the question be self-contained. Fiddle links are a nice *addition*, but must not be essential to understanding the question. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: jsfiddle link dead and you should use console.log :O

Comment: pls check now link is active

Comment: The guys fixed the dead link and this isn't a bad question

Comment: can anyone please come up with a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop through the rows in reverse order (from the bottom up). For each `td` that has data, look to see if the `td` at the corresponding index in the previous row is empty. If so, move the content into that row. You might use [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) or the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to access the previous row's `td`. You'd need multiple passes to handle cases where there were multiple blanks in a column, but the code is a lot simpler.

The more complex way is to work forward and shuffle the entire column when you find a blank. I was interested in what that looked like, so:

```
var rows = $("#xyz tr");
var row, n;

for (row = 0; row < rows.length - 1; ++row) {
  $(rows[row]).children().each(function(col) {
    var thisCell, cellBelow, text, foundText;

    foundText = true;
    thisCell = $(this);
    while (!thisCell.text() && foundText) {
      // This cell has no text, shuffle the column up
      foundText = false;
      for (n = row; n < rows.length - 1; ++n) {
        cellBelow = $($(rows[n + 1]).children()[col]);
        text = cellBelow.text();
        if (text) {
          foundText = true;
        }
        $($(rows[n]).children()[col]).text(text);
        cellBelow.text('');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ohafev/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ohafev/1/edit) *(sorry, can't **stand** jsFiddle -- slow and glitchy, in my experience)*

Now, that's fairly inefficient and does a shedload of DOM manipulations, but it works. Because of that, if the table is big, I'd be tempted to go another way, perhaps walk through the table once building up an array of column arrays, adding only non-blank cells to each column, and then replace the table entirely based on that new data.

Comment: Or `.previous()` on the parent `tr`.

Comment: Thats not working if you move a upper item. -> column |0|1|0|1| is then |1|0|1|0| and it should be |1|1|0|0| (0 is empty, 1 is filled). You can avoid such a scenario if you loop this approach x-1 times, where x is the number of rows.

Comment: @da_re: Yeah, it would take multiple passes, wouldn't it? Probably better to work through from beginning to end and shuffle the entire column up as necessary.

Comment: can somebody come up with a program please

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth: Remember, it's down to **you** to write your code, not us. Stack Overflow isn't a "give me teh codez" site. It happens I was interested in the problem and did decide to see what it took to solve it, but comments like "can somebody come up with a program please" sound a ***lot*** like "can somebody do my work for me please", which is likely to actively *prevent* people from taking an interest as I did. I really should have just left it at pointing you in the right direction rather than writing code.